# What will happen if a wild pokemon is hit by 2 pokeballs of the same strength at the same time?

Tags: pokemon

Wild Tauros appears.
Trainer A throws Safari Ball (Ball A).
Trainer B throws a Safari Ball (Ball B).

Now, a rare occurrence happens: both PokeBalls hit Tauros at exactly the same time. What will happen to Tauros? Will it enter Ball A, Ball B, or neither? Since PokeBalls converts Pokemon into energy before storing it, will it split in two and each trainer will have half a Tauros in each ball? Will this kill Tauros in the process? What if one of the balls is of better quality or strength? Like a normal PokeBall vs. a Great Ball?

Comment: It will split in two and each trainer will have half a Tauros. You will have to wait until this occurrence happens again to get another 1/2 Tauros.

Comment: Or, you can use your mangled half Tauros to make [Pokemon food](https://38.media.tumblr.com/2bc41e7f8d717d732307975d1182dd78/tumblr_mlx19ls0MD1sprxpdo1_500.gif)

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer:

*Pokémon: Let's Go, Eevee* and *Pokémon: Let's Go, Pikachu* introduce support trainers, a second player who aids the first player in battling other trainers and in capturing Pokémon. When the two trainers throw Poké Balls and hit a Pokémon at the same time, the Poké Balls combine and there is a greater chance the Pokémon will be caught.

Speculative answer:

In *Pokémon Adventures: Gold and Silver*, Kurt explained that Poké Balls work by using a "capture net", which is very similar to a real net. In fact, in the manga, the gym leader Bugsy does use a real net with his Poké Balls. So in the hypothetical case where two Poké Balls hit one Pokémon, the result would be similar to two nets being used. The nets would interfere with each other and neither one would fully encapsulate Taurus. Taurus possibly would be immobilized for a short time before it broke free from both nets. In the anime it would glow red and become energy for a moment.

From [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball):

> In the manga, Bugsy refers to his "capture net" as being the net that is supposedly inside a Poké Ball, but visible and already deployed. According to Kurt, this invisible net captures and physically stores a Pokémon.

As for better Poké Balls, such as a Great Ball, I would suspect their nets would be bigger and stronger, so they would be able to envelop the other Poké Ball's net and cancel it out. Thus, Taurus would be captured by the Great Ball.

Comment: Will Tauros be turned into energy by the two pokeballs? What do you mean by Tauros would get immobilized before break free? At this point has it turned into energy?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I don't know if I'd phrase it as becoming energy since I based my answer on the concept of the "capture net" from the manga. Then again, I don't claim to know exactly how Poké Balls work. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @AyaseEri The red energy stuff and return beam don't appear in the manga, you see. And Pokémon are often seen through the tops of the Poké Balls, so I don't think they become energy. Or they don't continue to be energy when they're in their Poké Balls, at least.